# If statement causes parsing but nothing else inside the branch

Tags: javascript, json, qt, qml, qtquick2

This is an odd one; This function is called by a timer every 1 second in Qt. Check out the `if` statement; first it parses some JSON data, then it logs that it is parsing. As I would expect, the `console.log` is only happening when `fileshow.txt` changes it contents. HOWEVER -- The line that says `var parsed = JSON.parse(t)` reports a parsing error every 1 second, even when nothing else (including the logging) occurs during that one second:

```
function get() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("GET", "/fileshow.txt");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var t = xhr.responseText;
        if (t != tt.lastData) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(t);
            console.log("parsing");

            viewer.newImages(parsed.files);
            thetime.shouldRepeat = parsed.repeat;
            thetime.fps = parsed.fps;
            tt.lastData = t;
            thetime.running = true;
        }
    }
    xhr.send()
}
```

Even though I get a parse error (which is a different topic -- the data is in fact parsing correctly despite the error, as it is getting routed via the above formulas just fine and other parts of the program get the data as expected), I should not even be seeing an error for that source code line unless that `if` branch actually runs! How can it report a parsing error that could only happen in that `if` branch when that `if` branch is not even running?!

There is no other parsing anywhere, and the error is reported for the specific line number of this JSON.parse call.

Comment: _"which is a different topic -- the data is in fact parsing correctly despite the error"_ How do you know this? Is this from performing `console.log` calls outside the method?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I am parsing the data as noted in the above code and data is correctly routing through my program. My question is not about the cause of the error itself but rather how a parsing can happen in the above code when nothing else in the `if` branch is happening? My JSON also passes a few online validators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking why the `if` statement executes, it's because `onreadystatechange` is called every time the state of the XHR request changes. There are [5 states for XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties):

- 0: UNSENT (`open()` has not been called yet)
- 1: OPENED (`send()` has not been called yet)
- 2: HEADERS_RECEIVED (`send()` has been called and headers and status are available)
- 3: LOADING (downloading; `responseText` holds partial data)
- 4: DONE (operation complete)

Because `onreadystatechange` will be called when it starts loading, you're getting passed in a partial JSON file, which is extremely unlikely to validate as proper JSON. You need to check that the `readyState` is 4, that is, it has finished loading:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && t != tt.lastData) {
```

You also probably want to check that the request was successful by checking for a HTTP 200 response. For more information about `XMLHttpRequest`, see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties).

Comment: oh this is beautiful. not only does this fix why the contents of the `if` were running, it also fixes the parsing error itself. nice!